# New Dataframe by matching keys of the dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dataframe in the form say df1

[image]

And another dataframe in the form say df2

[image]

Now for each day in the df2, I have to store the entire column from df1 corresponding to the group value in df2. For example: for 1876-08-18 I have the Group Number = 1. Hence I want to create a dictionary such that the key will be the date and the the entire column corresponding to df1 would be a column in dataframe.

Now my problem is I have 50 dataframes like df2. Hence for each day, I will have multiple columns. I am not able to append the columns properly.

Code tried:

```py
for i in range(len(obs1)): #this is the range of df2s 
    print(i)

    df = dd1[obs1[i]] #all the df2s
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    df = df.dropna(subset=['GROUPS'])
    df['GROUPS'] = df.GROUPS.astype(int)

    matrix = np.array(dd_replace[obs1[i]]) # this is df1

    dates = df["Date"].unique()
    for date in dates:
        daily_counts = df[df["Date"] == date]["GROUPS"]

        # Create a dictionary to store the calibrated counts for each day
        for count in daily_counts-1:
            # Find the column in the matrix corresponding to the count
            column = matrix[:, count]

            # Store the entire selected column for each day
            calibrated_counts_dict["Date"].append(date)
            calibrated_counts_dict["Column"].append(column)
```

Which gives the output:

> ```py
> {'Date': [numpy.datetime64('1893-10-31T00:00:00.000000000')],
>  'Column': [array([0.01827957, 0.45483871, 0.29247312, 0.12473118, 0.05268817,
>          0.02688172, 0.01505376, 0.00967742, 0.00215054, 0.00322581,
>          0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ])]}
> ```

​

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a _small_ example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: Can you include a sample of how you want the output to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your sample data, as a reproducible example:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.to_datetime([
        '1876-08-18', '1876-08-20', '1876-08-22', '1876-08-25', '1876-08-26',
        '1927-12-18', '1927-12-19', '1927-12-21', '1927-12-23', '1927-12-24']),
    'WOLF': [22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 31.0, 29.0, 16.0, 14.0, 28.0, 53.0, 98.0],
    'GROUPS': [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0],
    'SUNSPOTS': [12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 9.0, 6.0, 4.0, 18.0, 23.0, 38.0]},
    index=[24654, 24672, 24687, 24701, 24707, 171384,
           171387, 171390, 171393, 171397],
)
```

Then, to simulate "having 50 frames like `df2`", and just for the sake of this example, let's make another `df2` based on a random sample of `df2`, and shuffled groups:

```py
np.random.seed(0)  # reproducible example
b = df2.sample(frac=.8).reset_index(drop=True)
b['GROUPS'] = np.random.choice(df2['GROUPS'], b.shape[0])
>>> b
        Date  WOLF  GROUPS  SUNSPOTS
0 1876-08-22   0.0     2.0       0.0
1 1927-12-23  53.0     1.0      23.0
2 1876-08-26  29.0     1.0       9.0
3 1927-12-24  98.0     3.0      38.0
4 1876-08-20   0.0     3.0       0.0
5 1927-12-19  14.0     0.0       4.0
6 1927-12-21  28.0     1.0      18.0
7 1876-08-25  31.0     1.0      11.0
```

Assemble "all" the `df2`-like frames (only two here, but 50 of them in your case) into a list:

```py
frames = [df2, b]
```

Now, let's generate an arbitrary `df1`:

```py
n, m = 4, 8
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(n * m).reshape(n, m) / 10)
>>> df1
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
0  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7
1  0.8  0.9  1.0  1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5
2  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9  2.0  2.1  2.2  2.3
3  2.4  2.5  2.6  2.7  2.8  2.9  3.0  3.1
```

Now, a solution:

```py
# make each column a list
df1_lists = df1.T.apply(list, axis=1)
>>> df1_lists
0    [0.0, 0.8, 1.6, 2.4]
1    [0.1, 0.9, 1.7, 2.5]
2    [0.2, 1.0, 1.8, 2.6]
3    [0.3, 1.1, 1.9, 2.7]
4    [0.4, 1.2, 2.0, 2.8]
5    [0.5, 1.3, 2.1, 2.9]
6    [0.6, 1.4, 2.2, 3.0]
7    [0.7, 1.5, 2.3, 3.1]
```

Make a temporary Series `ser` with `Date` index (with possible duplicates) and `GROUPS` as value:

```py
ser = pd.concat([
    x.set_index('Date')['GROUPS'].astype(int)
    for x in frames
]).sort_index()
>>> ser
Date
1876-08-18    1
1876-08-20    0
1876-08-20    3
             ..
1927-12-23    3
1927-12-24    6
1927-12-24    3
```

And now:

```py
dct = {f'{t:%Y-%m-%d}': [df1_lists[i] for i in s] for t, s in ser.groupby('Date')}

>>> dct
{'1876-08-18': [[0.1, 0.9, 1.7, 2.5]],
 '1876-08-20': [[0.0, 0.8, 1.6, 2.4], [0.3, 1.1, 1.9, 2.7]],
 '1876-08-22': [[0.0, 0.8, 1.6, 2.4], [0.2, 1.0, 1.8, 2.6]],
 '1876-08-25': [[0.1, 0.9, 1.7, 2.5], [0.2, 1.0, 1.8, 2.6]],
 '1876-08-26': [[0.2, 1.0, 1.8, 2.6], [0.1, 0.9, 1.7, 2.5]],
 '1927-12-18': [[0.1, 0.9, 1.7, 2.5]],
 '1927-12-19': [[0.1, 0.9, 1.7, 2.5], [0.0, 0.8, 1.6, 2.4]],
 '1927-12-21': [[0.1, 0.9, 1.7, 2.5], [0.1, 0.9, 1.7, 2.5]],
 '1927-12-23': [[0.1, 0.9, 1.7, 2.5], [0.3, 1.1, 1.9, 2.7]],
 '1927-12-24': [[0.6, 1.4, 2.2, 3.0], [0.3, 1.1, 1.9, 2.7]]}
```